# Combine Two SAS Files Based on Two Columns in File A

Tags: merge, sas, mainframe

File A:

```
  C1(name)       C2(other name)
Apple      Fruit_1 Fruit_2
Orange     Fruit_1 Fruit_2
Carrot     Vegetable_1 Vegetable_2
Potato     Vegetable_1 Vegetable_2
```

File B:

```
 C1(name)    C2 (last used)
Apple        2014  
Fruit_1      2011 
Carrot       2010
Vegetable_2  2018
```

Desired Outcome:

```
  C1(name)       C2(other name)       C3(last used)
Apple      Fruit_1 Fruit_2           2014 
Orange     Fruit_1 Fruit_2           2011
Carrot     Vegetable_1 Vegetable_2   2018
Potato     Vegetable_1 Vegetable_2   2018
```

Basically I want to combine my files based on two columns in the first file. If "name" from file b is found in column C1 or C2 in file a then append date. Notice that for carrot the date is the same as Potato, that is because Vegetable_2 is has the most recent date and Vegetable_2 can refer to carrots or potatoes.

In my tests with MERGE, I cannot get merge to check a second column so I only get data for items that exist in C1 in both files.

so my current outcome is:

```
  C1(name)       C2(other name)       C3(last used)
Apple      Fruit_1 Fruit_2           2014 
Orange     Fruit_1 Fruit_2           
Carrot     Vegetable_1 Vegetable_2   2010
Potato     Vegetable_1 Vegetable_2
```

Any idea on what SAS process can be used to get my desired outcome? FYI I am using SAS on the mainframe. I am not sure if this changes anything because I have not used SAS outside of the mainframe environment.

Comment: This would require a SQL or hash solution, SQL is probably easier. Please post anything you've tried so far to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `Left Join` File B to A and use the `Contains` operator in your `On` clause.

So you left join if the table1.c1=table2.c1 or table2.c1 is subset of table1.C2(File A)

Dummy Data:

```
data file_a;
length c1 $ 8 c2 $ 30 ;
input c1 $ c2 $ ;
datalines;
Apple      Fruit_1,Fruit_2
Orange     Fruit_1,Fruit_2
Carrot     Vegetable_1,Vegetable_2
Potato     Vegetable_1,Vegetable_2
;
data file_b;
length c1 $ 12 c2 $ 4 ;
input c1 $ c2 $ ;
datalines;
Apple        2014  
Fruit_1      2011 
Carrot       2010
Vegetable_2  2018
;
```

Code:

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
select a.*, b.c2 as last_used  , b.c1 as cc
from file_a as a left join file_b as b
on a.c1= b.c1 or a.c2 contains b.c1
;
quit;
```

Output:

```
c1=Apple c2=Fruit_1,Fruit_2 last_used=2014 cc=Apple 
c1=Carrot c2=Vegetable_1,Vegetable_2 last_used=2010 cc=Carrot 
c1=Carrot c2=Vegetable_1,Vegetable_2 last_used=2018 cc=Vegetable_2 
c1=Potato c2=Vegetable_1,Vegetable_2 last_used=2018 cc=Vegetable_2 
c1=Orange c2=Fruit_1,Fruit_2 last_used=  cc=
```

Answer (score 1):

A merge only approach would require

- row-wise pivoting the first table
- sorting to prepare for the merge by any of the keys
- the merge
- sorting to restore original row order and descending year
- selecting the most recent year

Sample data

```
data foods;
length key1 $20 key2s $50;
input key1 key2s &; datalines;
Apple      Fruit_1 Fruit_2
Orange     Fruit_1 Fruit_2
Carrot     Vegetable_1 Vegetable_2
Potato     Vegetable_1 Vegetable_2
Knuckle    Sandwich_1 Sandwich_2
run;

data dates;
length key $20 year 8;
input key year; datalines;
Apple        2014  
Fruit_1      2011 
Carrot       2010
Vegetable_2  2018
Grain_1      2009
run;
```

Row-wise pivot each row, to get one row per key value

```
data food_single_keyed;
  length key $20;
  set foods;

  rowid = _n_;

  key = key1; output;
  do i = 1 by 1;
    key = scan(key2s,i); 
    if missing(key) then leave;
    output;
    if i > 10 then stop;
  end;
  drop i;
run;
```

Sort by key to prepare for merge by key

```
proc sort data=food_single_keyed;
  by key;
run;

proc sort data=dates;
  by key;
run;
```

Merge by key

```
data foods_dated;
  merge food_single_keyed dates;
  by key;
run;
```

Sort to prepare for final selections

```
proc sort data=foods_dated;
  by rowid descending year ;
run;
```

Select only first most recent associated year for a row.  You can also keep the `key` column to know which value was used to select the year.

```
data want (keep=key1 key2s year);
  set foods_dated;
  by rowid;
  if rowid;
  if first.rowid;
run;
```